# How to sort a tableview from array alphabetically but if a condition is true break that rule

Tags: swift

I have an array that populates a TableView. I sort the array alphabetically so the tableView will go from A - Z.

In my app a user can take one of the items in the array and mark it as 
"needs attention".

What I want to address here in this post is how I can take that item in the array that is now 'marked' and somehow put it FIRST in the array.

What I was thinking was if the item is 'marked' add "0000" to the beginning of the string because I think numbers are arranged before letters. And then when the user un marked it it would remove "0000" and therefore it would snap back to where it belongs. This option is great because if the user has marked several items then they would be first in the list and still be alphabetical.

However, I don't want the "0000" to show on the tableview because that is ugly.

So, my question here is...is there a way where as far as the code is concerned there IS a "0000" but the user can't see it. OR would it be better to somehow remove that item from the main array and create a second array? (Is this even possible)

This is the code that populates the array (as well as several other aspects of the app)

**Only showing relevant code **

```
func pullServicesForCard() {
    ...
    self.serviceArray.append(aService)
    self.serviceArray.sort { $0.serviceName < $1.serviceName }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please reduce the code pasted to only what is needed, because it is very hard to see what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Alistra, I found your code a little hard to follow - but I think I can see what you're after.

I have created an example with a struct for the key elements

```
struct TestData
{
    var name : String = ""
    var attention : Int = 0 // set to 1 to put at the top of the list
}
```

I then created some test data

```
arrayOfData.append(TestData(name: "f", attention: 0))
arrayOfData.append(TestData(name: "e", attention: 0))
arrayOfData.append(TestData(name: "bbb", attention: 1))
arrayOfData.append(TestData(name: "d", attention: 0))
arrayOfData.append(TestData(name: "c", attention: 0))
arrayOfData.append(TestData(name: "aaa", attention: 1))
arrayOfData.append(TestData(name: "b", attention: 0))
arrayOfData.append(TestData(name: "a", attention: 0))

arrayOfData.sort {
    if $0.attention == $1.attention { return $0.name < $1.name }
    return $0.attention > $1.attention
}

for t in arrayOfData
{
    print(t)
}
```

which produces this output - sorted by the `attention flag` and then by name

```
TestData(name: "aaa", attention: 1)
TestData(name: "bbb", attention: 1)
TestData(name: "a", attention: 0)
TestData(name: "b", attention: 0)
TestData(name: "c", attention: 0)
TestData(name: "d", attention: 0)
TestData(name: "e", attention: 0)
TestData(name: "f", attention: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by making a second array for "needs attention". Then, when you select an item in the first array, you can remove it from the first array and add it to the second array.

Then in your tableView, you can have 2 sections, the first section containing your "needs attention" array, and the second containing the original one. If you don't have any spacing between the sections, you should get the same effect.

In your didSelectRow function:

```
needsAttentionArray.append(firstArray[indexPath.row])
firstArray.remove(at:[indexPath.row])
```